# How to get a list of fields that are used in entities?

Tags: entities, 8

I want to retrieve all fields that entities are using (including locked fields).

How can I get a list of fields that are used in entities?

Like we get in admin/reports/fields.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically, or review a site's use of fields through the UI?

Comment: I want this programatically..

Comment: Why not just borrow the code from Drupal core then? FieldStorageConfigListBuilder.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend [EntityFieldManager::getFieldMap](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetFieldMap/8.2.x). The EntityManager is only a service to provide functions from other classes.

From documentation:

> **Return value**
>
> array An array keyed by entity type. Each value is an array which keys are field names and value is an array with two entries:
>
> - **type**: The field type.
> - **bundles**: An associative array of the bundles in which the field appears, where the keys and values are both the bundle's machine name.

Answer (score 5):

[`EntityFieldManagerInterface::getFieldMap()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManagerInterface.php/function/EntityFieldManagerInterface%3A%3AgetFieldMap/8.2.x) produces a keyed array by entity type > field name with further information on the field type and its associated bundles.

```
$field_map = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldMap();
$node_field_map = $field_map['node'];
$node_fields = array_keys($node_field_map['node']);
```

There's also [`EntityFieldManagerInterface::getFieldDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManagerInterface.php/function/EntityFieldManagerInterface%3A%3AgetFieldDefinitions/8.2.x) if you want further field metadata. It produces an array of [`BaseFieldDefinition`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Field!BaseFieldDefinition.php/class/BaseFieldDefinition/8.2.x) & [`FieldConfig`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!field!src!Entity!FieldConfig.php/class/FieldConfig/8.2.x) objects that you can parse through for further detail.

```
  $node_article_fields  =\Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('node','article');
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn,
I am not getting fields like they listed in above image.
Below field's i am getting:
`comment, 
contact_message, 
file, 
node, 
shortcut, 
taxonomy_term, 
user, 
menu_link_content`

Comment: There was a typo with the code. As mentioned with the answer, the function produces a keyed array that contains entities, field names, then field details.

Comment: Method 'entityManager' is deprecated. Use \Drupal::entityTypeManager() instead in most cases

Answer (score 2):

[`field_info_instance()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7.x) would do what you want, though if you look in the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7.x) you will see that in D8 it is deprecated in favour of

```
Field::fieldInfo()->getBundleInstance($entity_type, $bundle, $field_name).
```

Comment: Thank for your answer,
But i need to get list of all field(s) that are only in use. I don't want to get using by entity-type, bundle and field-name.
For reference uploading image.

Comment: The first link is spam, goes to steroids site.

Comment: Corrected - looks like drupalcontrib.org got hacked..

Answer (score 1):

Different ways to get field data:

Get a list of fields include base fields like nid.
(contains entity type, bundle, field name and field type).

```php
$field_map = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getFieldMap();
// Can also get by field type.
$field_map = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getFieldMapByFieldType('entity_reference');
```

Also see @shawn-conn's answer.

Get a list of storage fields and their data.
(non-bundle specific - e.g. 'node.field_image')

```php
// Get a list of storage fields
$field_config_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('field_storage_config')
  // Allow access to all regardless of permissons.
  ->accessCheck(FALSE)
  ->condition('type', 'entity_reference')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->execute();

// Load all the fields.
$field_config_entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_storage_config')->loadMultipleOverrideFree($field_config_ids);

// Get where each config is used.
foreach (field_config_entities as $field_config_entity) {
  $bundles = $field_config_entity->getBundles();
}
```

Get a list of field instances and their data.
(fields per bundle - e.g. 'node.story.field_image')

```php
$field_config_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('field_config')
  ->accessCheck(FALSE)
  ->condition('field_type', 'entity_reference')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->execute();
    
// Get also filter to only get feilds with a default value.
$field_config_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('field_config')
  ->accessCheck(FALSE)
  ->condition('field_type', 'entity_reference')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('default_value.0.target_uuid', NULL, 'IS NOT NULL')
  ->execute();
  
// Load the data.
$field_config_entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_config')->loadMultipleOverrideFree($field_config_ids);
```