# How to get field label from a field machine name

Tags: 8, entities

```
$fields = \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface->getStorage('field_storage_config')->loadMultiple();
```

This is listing me all the fields.

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $instance) {
   $label = $instance->getLabel();
   $name = $instance->getName();
}
```

$label is giving me **node.field_image**

$name is giving me **field_image**

My question is how can we get the label of the field in drupal 8

Answer (score 5):

The label is not stored in the field storage configuration. You'll find the label in the bundle specific field definition:

```
$definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'page');
foreach (array_keys($definitions) as $key) {
  // get label for field machine name $key:
  $label = $definitions[$key]->getLabel();
}
```

Reference: [EntityFieldManager::getFieldDefinitions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetFieldDefinitions/8.5.x)

Comment: This will give me field list of a bundle specific. How can i get the total fields list

Comment: The labels are bundle specific, so the node's image field can have a different label for each content type. See the edit to be more precise about the original question how to get the label for the field machine name. You could however loop over each bundle if you want to get a total field list. Then start with `\Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getAllBundleInfo();`

Comment: Although if you would ask for a total field lists I found this duplicate https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211057/how-to-get-a-list-of-fields-that-are-used-in-entities